# 3 position light switch beeps and flashes when down

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I’ve come across something I’ve never seen before and can’t find anything on the internet about. My house has a light switch by the front door that powers my exterior lights. The switch has 3 positions up = on, center = off, down = blinking lights and beeping switch?!

The house has built in the 1950’s and some circuits are non-grounded.

This is a mystery as I can’t find any information about this switch, how it works and what it’s purpose is. I’m going to pull it out of the wall later in a day or so, but wanted to see what I could learn beforehand. Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 31):

It sounds like an emergency light blinker, to let 911 responders or visitors know which house to go to.  Found on google this one,  [https://www.amazon.com/ge-7250269-emergency-flashing-activator/dp/b002w552ng](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/b002w552ng).  The beeping I think to let you know the lights are on blinking.

[image]